# How can I do to get the entries in an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Hello I have a Django query which contains this data :

```
id country begin               end
1  US      2020-10-07 15:30    2020-10-07 16:30
2  US      2020-10-07 16:30    2020-10-07 18:00
3  US      2020-10-07 19:00    2020-10-07 20:00
4  SP      2020-10-08 15:30    2020-10-08 17:30
5  SP      2020-10-08 17:30    2020-10-08 18:30
```

And using Django I would like to put in an array the data like this :

```
[{'country':'US', 'begin':'2020-10-07 15:30'; 'end':'2020-10-07 18:00'}, 
 {'country':'US', 'begin':'2020-10-07 19:00'; 'end':'2020-10-07 20:00'}, 
 {'country':'SP', 'begin':'2020-10-08 15:30'; 'end':'2020-10-08 18:30'}]
```

I get my table with the following query :

```
myTable = Table.objects.all().order_by('begin')
```

For the two first lines I don't know how to implement that... Basically I want if the country is the same and if one end 1 is equals to one begin 2 I want to put this in a same element in my array with begin 1 and end 2.

The line 3 stay like that because the begin 2020-10-07 19:00 is not equals to 2020-10-07 18:00
nor 2020-10-07 16:30 and the end 2020-10-07 20:00 is not equals to 2020-10-07 15:30 nor 2020-10-07 16:30.

For the fourth and fifth line we noticed the country are not US but SP. Then, the end of the fourth line is 2020-10-08 17:30 and the begin of the fifth line is 2020-10-08 17:30  so we can put this also in a same element.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv_str = """
id country begin               end
1  US      2020-10-07 15:30    2020-10-07 16:30
2  US      2020-10-07 16:30    2020-10-07 18:00
3  US      2020-10-07 19:00    2020-10-07 20:00
4  SP      2020-10-08 15:30    2020-10-08 17:30
5  SP      2020-10-08 17:30    2020-10-08 18:30
"""

col_spec = [(0, 2), (3, 10), (11, 30), (31, 50)]

with StringIO(csv_str) as f:
    df = pd.read_fwf(f, colspecs=col_spec, header=1)

for row_dict in df.to_dict(orient='records'):
    print(row_dict)
```

result:

```
{'id': 1, 'country': 'US', 'begin': '2020-10-07 15:30', 'end': '2020-10-07 16:30'}
{'id': 2, 'country': 'US', 'begin': '2020-10-07 16:30', 'end': '2020-10-07 18:00'}
{'id': 3, 'country': 'US', 'begin': '2020-10-07 19:00', 'end': '2020-10-07 20:00'}
{'id': 4, 'country': 'SP', 'begin': '2020-10-08 15:30', 'end': '2020-10-08 17:30'}
{'id': 5, 'country': 'SP', 'begin': '2020-10-08 17:30', 'end': '2020-10-08 18:30'}
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not what I want I wrote the result that I want in my post. The results is this : 

`[{'country':'US', 'begin':'2020-10-07 15:30'; 'end':'2020-10-07 18:00'}, 
 {'country':'US', 'begin':'2020-10-07 19:00'; 'end':'2020-10-07 20:00'}, 
 {'country':'SP', 'begin':'2020-10-08 15:30'; 'end':'2020-10-08 18:30'}]`

Comment: The semicolons too?